# Angular Erro: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou com problemas para setar valores dentro dos inputs do formulário.

Meu form.component.ts:

```js
    // Form
            this.constituicaoForm = this.fb.group({
                // Contrato
                descricao: ['', Validators.required],
                modalidade: ['', Validators.required],
                ...

                // Operações
                operacoes: this.fb.array([
                    this.fb.group({
                        tipoPessoa: ['', Validators.required],
                        numeroDocumento: ['', Validators.required],
                        ...
                    })
                ]),

                // Ativos
                ativos: this.fb.array([
                    this.fb.group({
                        tipoAtivo: ['', Validators.required],
                        idAtivo: ['', Validators.required],
                        ...
                    })
                ])
            });
```

Quando tento inserir um value no this.constituicao funciona normalmente utilizando esse código:

```js
this.constituicaoForm.controls.tipoAtivo.setValue("tipoTeste");
```

Mas quando tento inserir um value em operacoes ou ativos, dessa forma:

```js
this.constituicaoForm.controls.ativos[0].controls.descricao.setValue("teste");
```

Recebo esse erro no console do navegador (Chrome):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (editar-registro.component.ts:199)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
>       at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
>       at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)

E no terminal recebo esse erro:

> ERROR in
>   src/app/layout/content/registros/editar-registro/editar-registro.component.ts(198,53):
>   error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type
>   'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe nada no indice 0 por isso da undefined, para inserir um valor novo faça assim:

```
this.constituicaoForm.get('tipoAtivo').push("tipoTeste");
```